# Multiple registration of same domain

Tags: google-oauth

Can I register a single domain with multiple Google accounts? I have registered my domain for e-mail services already and verified it successfully. Now I want to use Google-Oauth service but have forgot the account details from which I have previously verified. So Can I now do this with another e-mail account?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to register a domain to multiple Google Apps accounts. You can [reset the credentials for the admin account](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33561), which will involve [re-verifying the domain using DNS](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33561#domainverify) if you don't have access to the secondary email account anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Could you give more details on how you are trying to 'register' OAuth? Are you trying to register/license a 3rd party application to become available to all users of your Google Apps domain, and the application needs OAuth to access user's data? Or are you trying to develop an application that uses the OAuth protocol and register it with Google?